# Docker on Azure .Net Core WebApi with continuous deployment - did it work?

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, continuous-deployment, azure-container-service

I followed the following: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure and everything appears to work just fine.  My build work and my Dev release was successful.

At the end of the documentation it says:

> 8. When the release has completed, browse to your web site, refresh the
>      page, and see that the change has been deployed.

But I have no idea what that url is?   How do I tell where that is or if everything did in fact work?  Sorry for the dumb question, I have never worked with any of this before - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's the URL you choose for your web app before.

See step 5 in the previous step "Define and test your CD release process":

> After the release is complete, navigate to your site running in Azure using the Web App URL http://{web_app_name}.azurewebsites.net, and verify its contents.

Comment: A Container Service is not a web app.  Also, what if I have 20 different containers?  They all can't have the same url - as you can see I am confused here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/new-docker-tools-for-visual-studio/

By doing it with Visual Studio, it creates by itself the complete pipeline which you can then modify or extend.

In the case you would like to have more than one service I recommend following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-setup-ci-cd

Both guides helped me to understand how ACS works, also will be worth watching the Docker section in the Visual Studio Lunch Keynote :)